# How to calculate all combinations of difference between array elements in 2d?

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

Given an array `arr = [10, 11, 12]` I want to calculate all the ways that one element can be subtracted from another. For a `1xN` array the desired output is a NxN array where `output[i, j] = arr[i] - arr[j]`. My approach was to generate all the possible pairings of two numbers, subtract, and reshape. As follows

```
opts = np.array(list(product(arr, arr)))
[[10 10] 
 [10 11]
 [10 12]
 [11 10]
 [11 11]
 [11 12]
 [12 10]
 [12 11]
 [12 12]]
 diffs = (opts[:, 0] - opts[:, 1]).reshape(len(arr), -1)
 [[ 0 -1 -2]
  [ 1  0 -1]
  [ 2  1  0]]
```

This works quite nicely, what I would like to do next is to generalize this to a 2d input. Essentially what I would like to accomplish is given an `MxN` array to output an `MxNxN` array, and for each layer (depth-wise) perform the above functionality for each row.

I attempted to reshape the `MxN` input array to be `MxNx1` and then calculate the product as before. My assumption was that it would behave element-wise the same as before, unfortunately not.

My first thought is to initialize an output of the appropriate shape and loop over the rows and set the values "manually" but I was hoping for a vectorized approach. Does anyone know how I can accomplish this in 2 dimensions without looping over thousands of rows?

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: `apply_along_axis()` worked like a charm

Comment: Two things - 1. Using `product` to generate the pairwise combinations isn't an efficient way. Alternative would be using `broadcasting`. 2. Using `apply_along_axis` is still looping under the hoods and hence another slowing factor. Posted timings in my post comparing all posted approaches, as the question listed `how I can accomplish this in 2 dimensions without looping over thousands of rows`, so seemed like performance is critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a generic vectorized way to cover both 1D and 2D cases leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) after reshaping the input array to broadcastable shpaes against each other -

```
def permute_axes_subtract(arr, axis):
    # Get array shape
    s = arr.shape

    # Get broadcastable shapes by introducing singleton dimensions
    s1 = np.insert(s,axis,1)
    s2 = np.insert(s,axis+1,1)

    # Perform subtraction after reshaping input array to 
    # broadcastable ones against each other
    return arr.reshape(s1) - arr.reshape(s2)
```

To perform any other elementwise [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) operation, simply replace the subtraction operation with it.

Sample run -

```
In [184]: arr = np.random.rand(3)

In [185]: permute_axes_subtract(arr, axis=0).shape
Out[185]: (3, 3)

In [186]: arr = np.random.rand(3,4)

In [187]: permute_axes_subtract(arr, axis=0).shape
Out[187]: (3, 3, 4)

In [188]: permute_axes_subtract(arr, axis=1).shape
Out[188]: (3, 4, 4)
```

Timings on [@ClimbingTheCurve's posted solution func - `permute_difference`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55353909/) and the one posted in this one on large `2D` arrays -

```
In [189]: arr = np.random.rand(100,100)

In [190]: %timeit permute_difference(arr, axis=0)
     ...: %timeit permute_axes_subtract(arr, axis=0)
1 loop, best of 3: 295 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.17 ms per loop

In [191]: %timeit permute_difference(arr, axis=1)
     ...: %timeit permute_axes_subtract(arr, axis=1)
1 loop, best of 3: 303 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.12 ms per loop
```

Comment: I suppose this is actually what I was looking for, I was certain that there was a fundamentally numpy-ish way to do this. It's elegant and brilliant. Unfortunately even after reading the documentation, it's still not fully clear to me how this works. Still it's more correct than my solution. I must accept.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to write a function for the 1d case and in order to generalize use the function `np.apply_along_axis()` which takes a function, an axis to apply along, and an input array. This works exactly as intended. 
The code I used:

```
from itertools import product

import numpy as np


def permute_difference(arr, axis=1):
    """
    applies the _permute_difference to a 2d array
    along the specified axis

    Parameters
    ----------
    arr numpy.array

    Returns
    -------
    numpy.array
        a 3d array, each 2d array the i^th along the depth
        contains the permuted difference of the i^th row
        in the input array
    """
    def _permute_difference(arr):
        """
        calculates all the differences between all combinations
        terms in the input array. output[i,j] = arr[i] - arr[j]
        for every combination if ij.

        Parameters
        ----------
        arr numpy.array
            a 1d input array

        Returns
        -------
        numpy.array
            a 2d array

        Examples
        --------
        arr = [10, 11, 12]

        diffs = [[ 0 -1 -2]
                [ 1  0 -1]
                [ 2  1  0]]
        """
        opts = np.array(list(product(arr, arr)))
        d = (opts[:, 0] - opts[:, 1]).reshape(len(arr), -1)
        return d

    if arr.ndim == 1:
        diffs = _permute_difference(arr)
    else:
        diffs = np.apply_along_axis(permute_difference, axis, arr)
    return diffs
```